# Web components with vaadin and rollup with svelte: Primary button ignores theme attribute

Tags: vaadin, web-component, svelte, rollup

Maybe someone tried this before and is able to give me a hint.
I have used normal svelte setup (mentioned in the main page) which scaffolds the app;

`npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project`

I wanted to use vaadin web components in Svelte. I've installed it;

`npm install @vaadin/vaadin`

the code of main.ts:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import '@vaadin/button/theme/material'

</script>

<main>
    <vaadin-button theme="primary">Primary</vaadin-button>
    <vaadin-button theme="secondary">Sec</vaadin-button>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        max-width: 240px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    @media (min-width: 640px) {
        main {
            max-width: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

And the thing is that it almost works :) The buttons are styled, I can click on them but... the theme is ignored;

[image]

The primary should have a background color like stated in docs;
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/button/#styles

any idea???

Comment: Reproduced in https://svelte.dev/repl/428d15b6186b493e8ce952842d3ccc08?version=3.46.4. Apparently the `theme` attribute is stripped in the final output. If you edit the HTML using dev-tools and add `theme="primary"` manually to your first button, then the button appears styled as intended. I currently have no idea *why* the attribute is being stripped however. Looking at the generated AST output, I can see the attribute is still part of the tree, so the stripping occurs beyond that step. This has nothing to do with the particular theme being applied (my repro example uses the default theme).

Comment: We've just tried with Vue 3. Same happens. If we set the attribute using devtools as You've described it works for both Svelte and Vue....

Comment: I tried to use different attributes from other components. They work, except the only one; theme. For example; <vaadin-checkbox-group label="Departments" theme="vertical" disabled> also has no effect.

Comment: This is very odd. Considering this happens both in Svelte & Vue, I'm afraid the answer lies directly within the vaadin implementation itself, and has nothing to do with either Svelte or Vue? Just an educated guess...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because of how Svelte sets data on custom elements. If a property exists on the element with the same name as the attribute you set, Svelte will set the property instead of the attribute. Otherwise, it will fall back to the attribute. So, the following...

```html
<vaadin-button theme="primary">Primary</vaadin-button>
```

...gets compiled to something like:

```js
button.theme = "primary";
```

Normally this works great, especially when setting array and object properties. However, the vaadin-button styles expect the `theme` *attribute* to be set, not the property. Because Svelte sets the property instead, the styles don't apply.

```css
:host([theme~="primary"]) {
  background-color: var(--_lumo-button-primary-background-color, var(--lumo-primary-color));
  color: var(--_lumo-button-primary-color, var(--lumo-primary-contrast-color));
  font-weight: 600;
  min-width: calc(var(--lumo-button-size) * 2.5);
}
```

I would argue that this is a Vaadin bug - if you expose an attribute and a property for the same data, it shouldn't matter which one the consumer sets. Setting the property should have the same effect as setting the attribute. A quick way to fix this would be for vaadin-button to reflect the theme property, so that setting `theme` also sets the attribute. Here's how to do that in [Lit](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#reflected-attributes).

However, that change requires the component library authors to implement it. As a consumer of the library, you can also work around this in Svelte by using an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) to force Svelte to set the attribute instead.

```svelte
<script>
  import "@vaadin/button";

  function setAttributes(node, attributes) {
    for (const [attr, value] of Object.entries(attributes))
      node.setAttribute(attr, value);
  }
</script>

<main>
  <vaadin-button use:setAttributes={{ theme: "primary" }}>Primary</vaadin-button>
  <vaadin-button>Normal</vaadin-button>
</main>
```

I wrote an article about this behavior and other workarounds at [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-custom-elements-in-svelte/), if you want a more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be importing the Material theme version of the Button component. The "primary" theme variant is only available if you use the default Lumo theme. To import that, use `import '@vaadin/button';`

For the Material theme, you can use the "outlined" and "contained" theme variants instead: https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-material-styles/1.3.2/demo/buttons.html

Comment: You are right, but the same happens if I set the theme="contained". If I change the import to Lumo, primary still doesn't work. See the first comment to the question.

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out, I was too hasty and didn't read the comments. I see there’s now an open issue for this: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/3483